# WLST identify the Multi Datasource.

Tags: passwords, datasource, wlst, identify

I have a script which needs to be updated. Currently it demands password for all the datasources but now we have some multi datasources as well along with the generic datasources. My requirement is that whenever the datasource is a multi datasource, it should skip that and shouldn't prompt for the password. I have listed the current script below.

```
def updateJDBCPasswords():

PARAMS_TEMPLATE = '/JDBCSystemResources/%s/JDBCResource/%s/JDBCDriverParams/%s'

domainConfig()

# Get JDBC DataSources
cd("JDBCSystemResources")
dataSources = cmo.getJDBCSystemResources()

edit()
# For each DataSource update the password
for dataSource in dataSources :
    dsName = dataSource.getName()
    password=raw_input("Enter database password for "+ dsName +" : ")
    cd(PARAMS_TEMPLATE % (dsName, dsName, dsName) )
    cmo.setPassword(password)
```

So far I have seen my threads/blogs but none of those is relevant to my problem. There is help for creating the multidatasources but couldn't find any hint how to identify it in order to satisfy my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly intuitive, but the root of serverConfig tree has a list of deployments which includes things like jdbc data sources and this is the only place I could find an mbean that allows you to identify multi data sources.  So the additional code at the start builds a list of names to ignore in your code.

```
serverConfig()

deployments=cmo.getDeployments()

multiDataSources = []

for deployment in deployments:
    if (deployment.getType()=="JDBCMultiPool"):
      multiDataSources.append(deployment.getName())

domainConfig()

# Get JDBC DataSources
cd("JDBCSystemResources")
dataSources = cmo.getJDBCSystemResources()

# For each DataSource update the password
for dataSource in dataSources :
    dsName = dataSource.getName()
    if dsName in multiDataSources:
        print("Skipping multidatasource %s" % dsName)
        continue

    print("Processing data source %s" % dsName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below can help:

```
         cd(_dsDir + '/JDBCDriverParams/NO_NAME_0/Properties/NO_NAME_0/Property/user')
            _userprop = cmo.getValue()

            # Multi datasource wouldn't have user properties and hence skipping the updation of multi datasources
            if _userprop is None:
                continue
            else:
                # continue updating password 
                cmo.setValue(_userval)
                # Next set the password
                cd(_dsDir + '/JDBCDriverParams/NO_NAME_0')
                set('PasswordEncrypted', _dsPassword)
```